# How do I change the full background color of the console window in C#?

Tags: c#, colors, background, console

In C#, the console has properties that can be used to change the background color of the console, and the foreground (text) color of the console.

```
Console.BackgroundColor // the background color
Console.ForegroundColor // the foreground/text color
```

The issue is that background color applies only where text is written, not to free space.

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; // background color is white
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;  // text color is blue
```

Now, with the above code, it does indeed turn the text blue, but it only turns the background of the text white, instead of the entire console window's background.

Here's an example of what I mean:
[image: The background only covers the background of the text, not of the entire console window]

As you can see, the white background only displays behind the text, and does not change the color of the entire console window.

How do I change the color of the entire console window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Background color on C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792066/change-background-color-on-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: Given the facts this question is **older** than the supposed duplicate and this one has an accepted answer but the newer question does not, I disagree with that assertion. I have already closed [Change Background color on C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792066/change-background-color-on-c-sharp-console-application) as a duplicate of this one. But this question should remain open.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to clear the console window AFTER setting the colors but BEFORE you write the text...

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you, not an obvious answer, but it worked exactly the way I wanted it too! The whole console window is now white!

Answer (score 5):

Pardon the shameless self-promotion, but I've created a [small plugin](https://github.com/silkfire/Pastel) (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pastel)) that allows you to add *any* (if supported by your terminal) color to your console output, without the limitations of the classic solutions.

It works by extending the `String` object, and the syntax is very simple:

```
"colorize me".Pastel("#1E90FF");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The running console controls the colors. You're essentially only changing the output of your application's color properties.

It's simple for changing the overall background color:
Click on the 'C:\' icon
Select Properties and choose the Colors tab.

Now if you're wanting to do this programmatically, you'll want to launch you're own window:

```
CMD /T:F[n color index]
```

---

### Color Value

Black 0
Blue 1
Green 2
Aqua 3
Red 4
Purple 5
Greenish Yellow 6
Light Gray 7
Gray 8
Light Blue 9
Light Green A
Light Aqua B
Light Red C
Light Purple D
Light Yellow E
Bright White F

Or if you're using PowerShell, refer to this TechNet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Clear();
            Array marks = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mark));
            foreach (var mark in marks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mark);
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

Comment: Try to add some description with your code. Why your solution work ? What your code does ?

Comment: Your answer is out of code block and without any description. Please consider reading the rules.

Answer (score -6):

This will work for you put it after your first open brace

```
{
        system("cls");
        system("color f3");
}
```

You can change the colors by number up to 7 I think example f1,f2,f3,f4... .

Comment: Sry, man, this is a c# question :) Downvoted just not to confuse others.