# Change Background color on C# console application

Tags: c#, colors, background, console

Ive searched the Web, but i cant seem to find the solution. I want my whole console application window to be a specific color, for example blue. How do I do that?

Comment: And how you are search? [Console.BackgroundColor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx)

Comment: are you looking for a way to make the whole black background a specific color, or are you looking for the answer Soner (with screenshot) provided?

Comment: In your try, you may forgot to add Console.Clear(); line after you set a color to Console.BackgroundColor

Answer (score 47):

Simply set the background color and call `Console.Clear()`:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The OP question was asking for how to set the entire background color to blue. None of the other samples shows this correctly. Here's how:

```
namespace ClearConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Clear();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set [`Console.BackgroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx) property to [`ConsoleColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) enumeration..

> Gets or sets the background color of the console. To change the background color of the > console window as a whole, set the BackgroundColor property and call the `Clear` method.

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Clear();
```

[image]

And you can use [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) property for

> Gets or sets the foreground color of the console.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
```

[image]

Comment: @SonerGönül first screenshot. there is a `console.clear();` command before that screen shot. so the whole background should be blue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.ForegroundColor = Color.Blue;
```

`Console.WriteLine("This string is blue!");`