# input consoleColor

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I get an input of `consoleColor` in c# console-application?

I tried a few options, and none of them was working:

```
ConsoleColor c = ConsoleColor.parse(Console.ReadLine());
ConsoleColor c = Console.ReadLine();
ConsoleColor c = (ConsoleColor)Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Background color on C# console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792066/change-background-color-on-c-sharp-console-application)

Answer (score 3):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns string input from user. `ConsoleColor` is enumeration. You need to parse input string to get enumeration value:

```
ConsoleColor color = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), Console.ReadLine());
```

Also keep in mind that user can input value which is not correct console color name. In that case it's better to try parse input:

```
ConsoleColor color;
if (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out color))
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered incorrect color name");
```

Answer (score 0):

One rather convenient way of getting such a color input would be through integer values. Users always want to type minimum. So, you can have integer/number based menu which correspond to enum values maintained internally by ConsoleColor enum as below:

```
public enum ConsoleColor
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color black.
        Black = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark blue.
        DarkBlue = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark green.
        DarkGreen = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark cyan (dark blue-green).
        DarkCyan = 3,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark red.
        DarkRed = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark magenta (dark purplish-red).
        DarkMagenta = 5,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark yellow (ochre).
        DarkYellow = 6,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color gray.
        Gray = 7,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark gray.
        DarkGray = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color blue.
        Blue = 9,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color green.
        Green = 10,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color cyan (blue-green).
        Cyan = 11,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color red.
        Red = 12,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color magenta (purplish-red).
        Magenta = 13,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color yellow.
        Yellow = 14,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color white.
        White = 15
    }
```

So on the console you show a menu to the user in something similar order:

```
Choose:
0 For Black
1 For DarkBlue
2 For DarkGreen
..and so on
```

Now simply read the integer input from console and use `tryPparse` API. `tryParse` API is equally helpful for parsing integral values as well and converting them into enum values:

```
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();//this will be an integer
ConsoleColor color = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor),userInput );
```