# How to Change The background Color In A Windows Console Application in C#

Tags: c#, colors, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 the code:

```
Console.BackgoundColor = Console.Color.Blue;
```

Does not work on Visual Studio

Does anyone know what I can do

I'm trying to change the background to green and back again

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the console after setting the colour as stated [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792066/change-background-color-on-c-sharp-console-application)

```
Console.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ConsoleColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx)

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
```