# Highlight text in WriteLine

Tags: c#, windows-console

I want to highlight text in WriteLine how can I do it?
For example Console.Write("Hello World"); and I want "World" to be in green color.
Can you guys help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the full background color of the console window in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524057/how-do-i-change-the-full-background-color-of-the-console-window-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Console.BackgroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=netcore-3.1) property.

The best practice would be:

```
// save the previous color
var prevColor = Console.BackgroundColor;

// set your color
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

Console.Write("Hello World"); 

Console.BackgroundColor = prevColor ;

// finally, reset all colors to originals.
Console.ResetColor();
```

Answer (score 1):

Example ( my default text color is Green )

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Hello");

    var prevColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

    // Set new text's color
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

    Console.Write(" World");

    // Restore old text's color
    Console.ForegroundColor = prevColor;

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image: Console text color]