# Set full background color of console

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to set a full background color instead of a highlighted word
and yes I'm aware that this works.

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Clear();
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

But I want it not to be Cleared, But apparently when I delete the sentence Console.Clear(); but it doesn't function properly as I tried this

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();`.
```

and the words were highlighted.

Is there answers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the full background color of the console window in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524057/how-do-i-change-the-full-background-color-of-the-console-window-in-c)

Comment: It clears the previous text.